# Method returns zero

Tags: java

It is suppose to return a value of 19 full seats and 68 students remaining!
please help, with my understanding I am returning the right values and assigning them to the correct variables!

```
public class JetCalculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int totalStudents = 3013;
        int jetCapacity = 155;
        int jets;
        int students;
        jets = calculateJets(jetCapacity, totalStudents);
        students = calculateStudents(jetCapacity, totalStudents, jets);

        System.out.println("A total of "+ totalStudents + " student require "+ jets + " full seated jets.");
        System.out.println("There will be " + students + " students remaining");
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________");
        System.out.println(jets);
        System.out.println(jetCapacity);
        System.out.println(students);
    }

    public static int calculateJets(int totalStudents, int jetCapacity)
    {
        int fullJets;
        fullJets = totalStudents / jetCapacity;
        return fullJets;
    }

    public static int calculateStudents( int jetCapacity, int totalStudents, int jets)
    {
        int remainingStudents;
        remainingStudents = jetCapacity * jets;
        return remainingStudents;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is more than one method there—which one returns zero and what do you expect it to return?

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged as such. And it would help if you stated the problem correctly. The answer is 19 full jets (jet where all seats are filled) with 68 students remaining, not "19 full seats".

Answer (score 5):

You call `calculateJets` this way

```
jets = calculateJets(jetCapacity, totalStudents);
```

But the argument names for this method imply that you've switched their order in the call

```
public static int calculateJets(int totalStudents, int jetCapacity)
```

This means you're actually doing `155 / 3013` which is `0` using integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks a hundred, have never felt so embarrassed to see my stupid mistake, but at least I learn out of it! thanks hey

Comment: @JaunLloyd glad I could help. You can green check-mark the answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in your parameters back to front.

You call `calculateJets` by passing capacity then students: `calculateJets(jetCapacity, totalStudents);` but the method asks for students then capacity: `calculateJets(int totalStudents, int jetCapacity)`.

This is a good argument for consistency in parameter order throughout a class interface.

To help debug this in future, try throwing in a `println` at the start of methods to see what is happening:

```
System.out.println("Called calculateJets with totalStudents of " + totalStudents + " and jetCapacity of " + jetCapacity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on method names: did you mean to say `remainingStudents = totalStudents - (jetCapacity * jets);` ?